# WPF - Two controls with a left margin of 0 placed differently

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an array of custom UserControls that I want to place from left to right in a grid inside a scrollviewer.

```
 <UserControl x:Class="TradingBot.UserControls.TradingObjects.Candle"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TradingBot.UserControls.TradingObjects"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50"
             d:DesignWidth="10">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Loaded="LayoutRoot_Loaded" SizeChanged="LayoutRoot_SizeChanged">
        <Rectangle x:Name="CandleBody_Rectangle" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Lime" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" Margin="0,6,0,0" MouseEnter="CandleBody_Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="CandleWick_Rectangle" Fill="Lime" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=LayoutRoot}" Margin="4,0,0,0" StrokeThickness="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MouseEnter="CandleBody_Rectangle_MouseEnter" Width="2"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I am placing them using the following method:

```
private void CreateCandle(out Candle candle, BinanceKline Kline, int candleIndex)
        {
            candle = new Candle(TypeOf(Kline), this.CandleWidth, ApplyVerticalScalingTo(Kline.Low) - ApplyVerticalScalingTo(Kline.High))
            {
                Name = string.Format("Candle{0}", candleIndex),
                BullishFill = this.BullishCandleFill,
                BearishFill = this.BearishCandleFill,
                Width = this.CandleWidth,
                WickThickness = this.WickThickness,
                Height = ApplyVerticalScalingTo(Kline.Low) - ApplyVerticalScalingTo(Kline.High),
                Margin = new Thickness(candleIndex * (this.CandleWidth + this.CandleSpacing), ApplyVerticalScalingTo(Kline.High), 0, 0),
                Tag = Kline,
        };
        candle.CandleBody_Rectangle.Height = Math.Abs(ApplyVerticalScalingTo(Kline.Close) - ApplyVerticalScalingTo(Kline.Open));
        if (candle.CandleBody_Rectangle.Height == 0) candle.CandleBody_Rectangle.Height = WickThickness;
        candle.CandleBody_Rectangle.Margin = new Thickness(0, candle.Height - (candle.Height / (double)(Kline.High - Kline.Low) * (double)((((TypeOf(Kline) == Candle.CandleType.Bullish)? Kline.Close:Kline.Open) - Kline.Low))), 0, 0);
    }
```

After which I use

```
Chart_Grid.Children.Add(candle[i]);
```

The problem is that even though they should start being placed from the grid's 0 left point, they are being placed from the middle point of the grid.
If I try to place a textblock (for example) at (0, 0) it is placed correctly.

[image: Description]
[image: Proof]

I feel like there is something wrong with the Candle element but I can't figure out what.

Comment: It is possible that your Grid itself starts at the center. Try to set the Grid.HorizontalAlignment to Stretch and test. Try to use Snoop to figure out the runtime position of controls. That might help.

Comment: I made the grid a canvas instead and it's working as it should.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked out in the end. I did doubt it was the Grid playing up.

Comment: it's probably got something to do with Extended WPF Toolkit, it makes things go crazy sometimes